# Error creating bean with name 'springProjectController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; Could not autowire field:

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Stack trace
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springProjectController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.springproject.service.SpringProjectservice com.springproject.controller.SpringProjectController.springservice; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springProjectServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.springproject.dao.SpringProjectDao com.springproject.service.SpringProjectServiceImpl.springprojectdao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springProjectDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.springproject.dao.SpringProjectDaoImpl.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.springproject.service.SpringProjectservice com.springproject.controller.SpringProjectController.springservice; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springProjectServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.springproject.dao.SpringProjectDao com.springproject.service.SpringProjectServiceImpl.springprojectdao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springProjectDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.springproject.dao.SpringProjectDaoImpl.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>


SpringDispatcher-servlet.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
<!--  
    <mvc:annotation-driven/> -->
    <context:annotation-config /> 
    <context:component-scan base-package = "com.springproject.controller" />

     <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lo" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="springprojectdao" class="com.springproject.dao.SpringProjectDaoImpl">
         <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean> 
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
     <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

</beans>
```

SpringprojectController

```
package com.springproject.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.springproject.bean.Bean;
import com.springproject.service.SpringProjectservice;

@Controller
@ComponentScan("com.springproject.service")
public class SpringProjectController 
{
    @Autowired
    private SpringProjectservice springservice;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public String getview() {
        return "Login";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value= "/usercheck", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String Usercheck(@ModelAttribute("form") Bean login)
    {
        System.out.println("" + login.getUsernameid());
        System.out.println("" + login.getPasswordid());
        String value = springservice.usercheck(login);
        return "success";
    }

}
```

@Serviceimpl

```
package com.springproject.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.springproject.bean.Bean;
import com.springproject.dao.SpringProjectDao;


@Service
@ComponentScan("com.springproject.dao")
public class SpringProjectServiceImpl implements SpringProjectservice 
{
    @Autowired
    SpringProjectDao springprojectdao;

    @Override
    public String usercheck(Bean login) {

        return springprojectdao.usercheck(login);
    }


}
```

DAOImpl

```
package com.springproject.dao;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.springproject.bean.Bean;

@Repository
public class SpringProjectDaoImpl implements SpringProjectDao {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate ;
    @Override
    public String usercheck(Bean login) {
        String SQL = "select count(*) from login where username = ? AND password = ? ";
        int flag = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(SQL, new Object[]{login.getUsernameid(),login.getPasswordid()});
        return String.valueOf(flag);
    }



}
```

Comment: The definition of the JdbcTemplate bean is commented out. And you get "No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]". why does that surprise you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583996/could-not-autowire-field-private-org-springframework-jdbc-core-jdbctemplate)

Comment: jdbc template bean - that I have commented on purpose..but before that only spring is unable to wire the beans in controller - SpringProjectservice springservice;

Comment: It looks like the service package should be added: 
base-package="com.springproject.controller,com.springproject.service"